# Visual Studio 2017 lost intellisense and coloring with #else directive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, preprocessor-directive

I just started to use preprocessor directive in my code on VS 2017 and how somehow the editor lost its intellisense and coloring within the #else directive...I can't find anything from Google.  Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that doesn't make it in the final built binary is inactive and marked as such by being grayed out.

Most likely you've selected the Debug configuration on the drop down on top of Visual Studio. If you pick Release, the code will not be grayed out anymore.

Comment: that's exactly it!  Thank you...will accept as answer.